# R: unused argument in layer function

Tags: r, ggplot2, layer

I am trying to plot a math function in R. 
I've tried to recreate the code from the following website:
https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/ggplot2-stat-function

Here is my code:

```
a <- 1;
b <- 1;

p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x))

brem_nosc <- function(x) (1 + x^2 - (2*x/3))*(log(x) - (1/2))

p + layer(geom = "path",        # Default. Can be omitted.
          stat = "function",
          fun = brem_nosc,          # Give function
          mapping = aes(color = "fun.1") # Give a meaningful name to color
          ) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5,5)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Function", values = c("blue"))
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Error in layer(geom = "path", stat = "function", fun = brem_nosc, mapping = aes(color = "fun.1")) : 
  unused argument (fun = brem_nosc)
```

I can't figure out why the function isn't getting recognized. What could be the issue?
Thank you for reading

Comment: The docs (`?ggplot2::layer`) do not suggest an argument `fun=`. It does say that if `data=` is a `function`, when it will be called *"with a single argument, the plot data. The return value must be a 'data.frame.', and will be used as the layer data."* To me, this suggests your `brem_nosc` should be returning a frame. (Unless I'm misunderstanding your needs or `layer`.) (FYI: ggplot2-3.0.0)

Comment: @r2evans I've converted the function into a datafram and applied ggplot. Thank you!

Comment: I found this fun argument here https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/ggplot2-stat-function and I cannot replicate it. Would have been great if there was a code solution on this question.

Answer (score 1):

When the 'stat' argument of layer is set to "function", the function must be passed in a list assigned to the 'params' argument. Using your example, you should enter

```
p + layer(geom = "path", stat = "function", params = list(fun = brem_nosc),mapping = aes(color = "fun.1"))
```